# jquery only change one element

Tags: php, jquery

Hello I have a php page that show 10 articles with read more button hidden all I need is when I hover on the article box the read more show everything is working fine expect when I hover on anything it show read more on first article only not every article

This is my php code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stories ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<div class='content_story_block'>
            <div class='content_story_block_menu'>$row[title]
                <div id='Read_More' style='display:none;' class='content_story_block_menu_span'>Read More</div>
            </div>
            <div class='content_story_block_row'>$row[brief]</div>
         </div>";
}
```

and this is my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.content_story_block').hover(function() {
      $('#Read_More').toggle('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
</script>
```

what am I missing ?

Comment: using the same id 'Read_More' one more than one element is actually not valid markup and is the reason why your code is failing. try making it a class or assign different IDs to each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Read_More` from id to class:

```
<div style='display:none;' class='content_story_block_menu_span Read_More'>
Read More</div>
```

Then change your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.content_story_block').hover(function() {
      $(this).find('div.Read_More').toggle('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When I hover on any article all read more button shows not only the one with this article

Comment: Thanks this is saved me :) +1 and good answer and i learned what i was missing thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.content_story_block').hover(function() {
      $(this).next('#Read_More').toggle('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sane Thing as the previous reply when iam hovering on article all read more button show not only the one with this article

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.content_story_block').hover(function() {

 $('.content_story_block_menu_span').each(function(){
      $(this).toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
  })
});
```

Comment: You need to use .each() to handle the every element of matched category

Comment: when i hover on article all read more button show not just one i dont know why all codes make the same result